# Why would you ever use workflow field updates if custom validation rules are in place?

Tags: trigger, workflow, process-builder, validation

I have been researching on what is the better of the three (Triggers/Workflow/Process Builders) to make field updates or to perform any action which can be performed by all the three tools. However, the answers were more of opinions rather than proper logics to explain which one is apt for which use-case scenario.

According to what I read, we should always prefer workflow rules or process builders until there is any custom requirement which cannot be achieved by one of these two.

However, when I came across execution order of salesforce, I came to know that after workflow rules are fired, custom validation rules are not run again. In that case, I believe, whole purpose of validation rules, which is to prevent bad data, is defeated.

If that is the case, wouldn't it make sense to always use triggers for field updates rather than workflow or process builder rules so that validation rules are always obeyed?

And if that makes sense, why most of the blogs suggest that we should be using UI tools rather than triggers?

Please guide me if I have missed any point which explains the use of workflow/process builder for field updates.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of cases where a user shouldn't be allowed to update a field value, but that value may still be legal. For example, perhaps a Status field allows me to set the value to Pending or Canceled, but not Approved. In order to Approve a record, an Approval Process must be followed. In that manner, the manager can approve the record, but the user can't. Further, once approved, the user can be prevented from changing it to another status, like Canceled. By using a combination of validation rules and Workflow Rules and Approval Processes, you can create conditions where a user can't bypass your organization's business logic without interfering with the business logic itself.

As far as triggers are concerned, writing code typically also means unit tests. It is far simpler to simply create a Process or Flow, perhaps even directly in Production, without the need to prepare the trigger, write a unit test, validate that the tests run without fail, code coverage, weird edge case logic, etc. In an ideal world, Apex wouldn't be necessary for any logic at all, and everything could be point-and-click (or, at least, something you can set up directly in the UI). Apex is meant to be used for advanced logic that would be non-trivial or even impossible to do with UI tools alone.

Alongside that point, not everyone is a developer, and not every org can afford developers; they're relatively expensive (a developer can often easily get 150%-200% or more salary than a "simple" System Administrator role). For many SMBs, code development is a luxury item, and has to be budgeted carefully (consulting companies are typically 2-4x more expensive per hour than in-house salary developers). This means that the UI options provide automation to the masses that might otherwise be out of reach.

Once you start needing to mix the two, though, it's almost always better for performance reasons to ditch the UI tools. They are convenient, but that convenience has a cost in terms of the amount of time it takes to save a record. A well-designed trigger will execute faster than workflow rules/processes that perform the same logic. However, that also requires a level of expertise you're less likely to find in junior developers. This makes the UI option far less expensive on average.

All that said, experienced developers would still use flows and processes if it were the right tool for the job, because there are times when it is faster and simply easier to maintain. Those developers that have learned how to use all the tools will typically end up making the right choice in which tool to use, which is something you only learn with experience.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your direct question: **why would you set up a field update to put in bad data on the object?** Ideally, a field update that's automated would be using "correct" data

Otherwise, I think the general question (using which automation tool) is a complicated one that has a degree of opinion and differences on a case-by-case basis.

However, in situations like these I think it's important to look at what Salesforce already provides as [Best Practices for Designing Processes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_considerations_design_bestpractices.htm&type=5).

The biggest notes:

1. **For each object, use one automation tool**
2. **Have only one record-change process per object**

It's a pain to debug when, as you've noted, you have workflow field updates executing later on in the process and potentially having your trigger execute a couple times.

[image]